# Import multiplayer - GameKit on iOS Game

Tags: ios, multiplayer

I finally created succesfull my quiz-trivia game with SQLite database. Now i am trying to import gamekit to the game. My question is when i send a data packet to the peers with an array the other device receives wrong answers from the packet. Here is my code:

```
NSMutableArray * questionArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
            [questionArray addObject:newText];
            [questionArray addObject:ans1];
            [questionArray addObject:ans2];
            [questionArray addObject:ans3];
            [questionArray addObject:ans4];
            //questionArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: newText,ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4, nil];
            NSData * questionData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:questionArray];
            [mySession sendDataToAllPeers:questionData withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable error:nil];
```

Here i create my data array and in receivedata method i place it on labels

```
-(void)receiveData: (NSData *)data fromPeer:(NSString *)peer inSession: (GKSession *)session context: (void *)ctx {

[mySession setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil];
NSMutableArray * recievedQuestion = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
NSLog(@"%@", recievedQuestion);

self.question.text = [recievedQuestion objectAtIndex:0];
[recievedQuestion removeAllObjects];
```

and here is a log from the device with duplicated data.

**2013-10-20 14:00:38.382 P2P[589:c07] (
    "Which one of the following countries won the world cup (football) in 2006?",
    Italy,
    France,
    Portugal,
    Italy
)**

As you can see i recieve duplicated answer. Can someone explain me why that is happening?

Comment: Duplicated answer? Where?

Comment: The word Italy is twice on the data that reeceives the second device as you can see nomannasim on the log.

Comment: I used Archivers a lot but never encountered these type of issues and you are not coding you custom objects (which have their own coding methods) so please make sure you that ans1 and ans4 had different values in the first place.

Comment: i am sure my friend that had different values because i can see the difference on the device that send the data. One question nomannasim from your experience, is it difficult to use gamekit for a trivia-quiz game because i find a little bit hard!